# Replacing values of a column with its minimum value in sas

Tags: sas

i am very new to sas and I have the following work table

[image]

I want to create a new table in which column Date and Z remain the same, but all values in column X are replaced with the minimum value in column X and all values in column Y are replaced with the minimum value in column y.

Sample output is as follows

[image]

Comment: You really should be showing whatever you've tried so far to solve this issue on your own first [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that PROC SQL will automatically remerge aggregate statistics back onto detail observations.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select date, x, min(y) as y, min(z) as z
    from have
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use proc sql statement you can modify this code found from https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/12/01/max-and-min-rows-and-cols.html

```
data MinMaxRows;
   set sashelp.Iris;
   array x {*} _numeric_;    /* x[1] is 1st var,...,x[4] is 4th var */
   min = min(of x[*]);       /* min value for this observation */
   max = max(of x[*]);       /* max value for this observation */
run;
proc print data=MinMaxRows(obs=7);
   var _numeric_;
run;
```